# Change custom post type url

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've a custom post type by name 'Portfolio'. It's generating the url as /portfolio/xxx when I make any post. I want to change it to 'Products'.
[Change custom post-type rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089935/change-custom-post-type-rewrite)
I've tried this  but it doesn't suppose to work.

Comment: What does the code you used to generate the custom post type look like?

Comment: This comes with the theme

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am presuming you have added the custom post type yourself, in which case it is easy.

When you register a new post type, you can set any rewrite rules for that post type to follow as part of the arguments used in the `register_post_type( 'name', $args )` function.

If your post type is available on the front end and is public, then by default WordPress will use the custom post name as the slug. You can override this as follows:

```
$args = array(
    // your other arguments
    'rewrite' => array( 
        'slug' => 'products', // use this slug instead of post type name
        'with_front' => FALSE // if you have a permalink base such as /blog/ then setting this to false ensures your custom post type permalink structure will be /products/ instead of /blog/products/
    ),
);

register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );
```

The other arguments you can use are documented at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 3):

Please see the documentation on [URLs of Namespaced Custom Post Types Identifiers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs_of_Namespaced_Custom_Post_Types_Identifiers). One of the options available to you is to add a `'rewrite'` argument to [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). From the docs:

> When you namespace a custom post type identifier and still want to use a clean URL structure, you need to set the rewrite argument of the register_post_type() function. For example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
function create_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    )
  );
}
```

You'll then likely need to login to the admin and re-save your permalinks.

Comment: It *does* work. In fact, it's the only way it should work. We need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: I've posted your code in functions.php and it is not working. You need to understand this.

Comment: Of course my code doesn't work. It's not a drop-in piece of code. You need to modify your OWN code.

Comment: Dude, I'm not expertise in deep coding of php. That's why I posted here to ask how to achieve that..

Answer (score 1):

Use the rewrite property

```
$args= array(
    // other settings
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Products' ),
);
register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args);
```